# JQGrid loading disables(grays out) JQuery UI tab

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-tabs

Hi I am currently using JQGrid inside a JQuery UI Tab. My problem is that when I call the render JQGrid it disables(Grayed out with diagonal stripes).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divTimePeriod").tabs();

        jQuery("#listTimePeriod").jqGrid({
            url: '/TimePeriod/GetTimePeriods',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['', 'TimePeriodKey'],
            colModel: [
          { name: 'Actions', index: 'Actions', width: 60, sortable: false },
          { name: 'TimePeriodKey', index: 'TimePeriodKey', width: 55 },
        ],
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: "result"
            },
            pager: '#pagerTimePeriod',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridComplete: function () {

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<h3>Time Period Service</h3>
<div id="divTimePeriod">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#TimePeriod">Time Period</a></li>
        <li><a href="#DayType">Day Type</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Interval">Interval Group</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Calendar">Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="TimePeriod">
       <span>Name: </span> <select><option></option><option>Default</option><option>All</option><option>Summer Off/On Peak</option></select>
        <table id="listTimePeriod" width="100%"></table> 
        <div id="pagerTimePeriod"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="DayType">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/DayType/Contents.ascx"); %>
    </div>
    <div id="Interval">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/IntervalGroup/Contents.ascx"); %>
    </div>
    <div id="Calendar">
        Calendar
    </div>
</div>
```

The grid renders correctly but the tab remains grayed out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until the tab is initialized before creating your jqGrid.

For example, you can place your initialization code in the tab's [show event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#events), so that it is not executed until the tab is ready:

```
$("#divTimePeriod").tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) { 
     if (ui.index == 0){ // First tab is shown...
        // Initialize your jqGrid here
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Justin, but it still displays similar problem.

Comment: You could try temporarily commenting-out the content from the other tabs to see if one of them is causing the problem. Beyond that, I think you are going to have to post more of your code in order for us to begin to narrow-down the problem.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will first try your suggestion and post an update.

Comment: Hi Justin. Just found out that the problem was just i missed to include the <link href="../../Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />. Oh my. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad you tracked it down :)